# What's the best way to label new categories within a feature?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

is there a way how to manually assign numerical labels for a feature cutted into bins?

I've tried:

```
data['AgeBin'] = pd.cut(data['Age'].astype(int), 5, labels = [1,2,3,4,5])
```

and though labels are to be defined as an integer, they seems to be actually a string.

I did remaping using

```
age_mapping = {'1':1, '2':2, ...}
data['AgeBin'].map(age_mapping)
```

which works but I'm really curious if there's a better way without using LabelEncoder as I want to remain ordinality for my feature and I'd like to avoid OHE here.

I was also wondering about creating age density count but not sure how to write it to be honest.

Comment: "and though labels are to be defined as an integer, they seems to be actually a string" it doesn't look like it though??

Comment: `data["AgeBin"].values`

`Out:`
 
`Categories (5, int64): [1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5]`

the categories are in fact ordered (of course I don't have your dataset).

Comment: As for the age density part. I am not sure what you are asking. Something like this?
`sum(data["AgeBin"][data["AgeBin"]==1])/len(data)`